# POST a file to Document library using java

Tags: document-library, file

How do I make a post request to a document library using java?

I'm using the lastest version on this library http://hc.apache.org/

This is my post request right now:

`itemUrl` looks like this: `http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/enovia/FILENAME.txt`

```
public void addItem(String itemUrl, File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    HttpEntity test = new InputStreamEntity(fileInputStream);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(itemUrl);
    System.out.println("ITEM URL: " + itemUrl);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    request.setEntity(test);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context);
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    System.out.println("STATUS CODE POST: " + response.getStatusLine());

}
```

I'm getting a status code:

> 200 OK

but my document library is empty and nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it so ill answer my own question:

```
 public void addItem(String itemUrl, File file) throws IOException {
    TempFiles tf = new TempFiles();
    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(itemUrl);
    request.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
    System.out.println("ITEM URL: " + itemUrl);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context);
    System.out.println("STATUS CODE POST: " + response.getStatusLine());
    tf.deleteTempFiles();

}
```

I removed the headers and changed to httpPut instead of httpPost. I got a error code: 404 when i used httpPost, dont ask me why. Maybe someone else can answer that question here.
I also used `FileEntity` in my `request.setEntity`.